# Collections of Homomorphic (defined) structures via $f$

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology, abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

Long ago I read a text about a collection of algebraic sturctures all homomorphic (or isomorphic) via a unique homomorphism

An Example similar to the construction I found was this:

Lets take define $\mathcal U $ as the union of infinite pairwise disjoint sets $U_i$

$$\mathcal U=\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N}U_i$$

and we take a one-to-one function $f:\mathcal U \rightarrow \mathcal U$ with this property:

for every element of $x\in\mathcal U$ if $x\in U_k $ then his image $f(x)\in U_{k+1}$ and thus we have

$$f[U_k]=U_{k+1}$$

Now if we build an algebraic structure $\mathbb U_0$ on $U_0$ lets say adding an unit element and defining on it a binary operation and lets say an order relation $\mathbb U_0=(U_0,k_0,*_0,<_0)$ in this way we are able to define another algebraic structure $\mathbb U_1$ on $U_1=f[U_0]$ that is homomorphic to $\mathbb U_0$.

I can perform this construction infinite times defining $\mathbb U_{n+1}$ from $\mathbb U_{n}$ in the following way

> *i)*$\mathbb U_0:=(U_0,k_0,*_0.<_0)$
>
> *ii)* $\mathbb U_{n+1}=(f[U_n],f(k_n),*_{n+1} ,<_{n+1})$
>
> *iii)* For every $a,b \in U_n$ then $f(a*_nb)=f(a)*_{n+1}f(b)$
>
> *iv)*  $f(a)<_{n+1}f(b)$ only if $a<_nb$

What I obtain (I guess) is an infinite collection of algebraic structures $\{\mathbb U_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ all pairwise homomorphic in this way

> $\mathbb U_n$ is homomorphic to $\mathbb U_{n+1}$ via $f$
>
> $\mathbb U_t$ is homomorphic to $\mathbb U_{s}$ via $f^{\circ s-t}$

This is most important property that holds for all this kind of constructions.

I used a collection of structures with binary operations only as example but maybe these constructions can be made on more general objects

> Q1-There is a branch of mathematics, maybe a theory, that use often
>   similar costructions? Are these interesting and usefull objects somewhere
>   in the mathematical landscape or are useless?
>
> Q2- If yes maybe these constructions are already well studied (maybe in Category Theory), can you
>   give me some **references?**

EDIT

**Someone voted for the closure of this question because is too broad.**

**If it is then I didn't know it.
Thats why I ask this question. If this subject is too common then there should be a good formalization of these constructions and I am in fact asking for good references too, since I did not found nothing on wikipedia. (Probably I don't know the terminology and that explains the Tags)**

Comment: Can you specify a bit? What was the title of that text or who wrote that? Maybe another example or this example more detailed would help us..

Comment: Ok, i'll add more examples in the next hours.

Comment: Updated with a more concrete example @Berci
I must remember that this is only an example but I'm interested in the concept behind it. By the way I don't think that knowing the autor can be usefull for this, what I know is that the book he wrote is the only one where I saw this contruction ...but that doesn't mean nothing since my knowledge of math books is very small.

Comment: Thanks for updating, it is getting to make much more sense now. Well, can you confirm that $f$ being '*one-to-one*' between $U_n$ and $U_{n+1}$ wants to mean that it is a *bijection* $U_n\to U_{n+1}$ when restricted to $U_n$? If yes, then the word you used '*homomorphic*' would rather be '*isomorphic*', and in this case, this example seems not particularly interesting, since you just copy one arbitrary structure $\Bbb U_0$ for infinitely many times. (You could instead also take the set $\Bbb N\times{\Bbb U_0}$..)

Comment: Thanks @Berci but this is only the easier exemple I was able to give but the construction can be made more general: maybe the one-to-one requirement could fail or we can have weaker requirmenets. The interesting thing is the fact that in this way $\mathcal U$ can be seen as a larger structure equiped with an infinite chain of homomorphic algebraic structures defined by $f$. I am not very expert of category theory but since I found this idea I believed it was a very common structure, or at least well studied.

Comment: @MphLee: I was looking over my Q/A and I remembered this question. I'd like to offer a bounty for it, but I'd like one piece of clarification: would it be fair to say that you are looking for a general theory which describes chains $U_1\to U_2\to\cdots$ of surjective homomorphisms?

Comment: I'm not sure. @EricStucky , I'm interested in chains of homomorphic structures where the homomorphism is always the same function. Obviously the main case I'm interested in is with a bijective function so that Berci's comment is applied as an anwser, but I'm interested in the generalized costruction too. **Continue**

Comment: **continue** 
Anyways I'm looking for chains of homomorphic structures (objects) $(\Bbb {U}_i)_{i\in\Bbb Z}$ rather than chains of homomorphisms.
The chain of structures are defined on a sequence of (I guess not necessarily disjoint ) portions $(U_i)_{i\in\Bbb Z}$ of a bigger  collection $\mathcal U$ on wich is defined the map $f$.
Long time is passed since I asked this and now I see that my definition is weak and probably it doesn't exclude trivial cases. So I don't think is a nice thing to waste a bounty on this right now. I may be wrong.